# Mysql: Increment variable in UPDATE SET command

Tags: mysql

How to `UPDATE mytable` and `SET foo = myvar`, `myvar` being equal to `1` at the beginning and being incremented for each new row to be set ?

I've tried this command:

```
SET @myvar = 1; SELECT characters SET radnum = (SELECT @myvar := @myvar + 1) ;
```

But I get the following error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET radnum = (SELECT @myvar := @myvar + 1)' at line 1
```

Comment: You want to `UPDATE` but you have written `SELECT` instead...

Comment: Try `update mytable set foo = @myvar:=(@myvar+1) where 1=1;`

Comment: @Nick Indeed... thanks!